# Which countries adopt metacognition in their official math curricula?

Tags: curriculum, meta-cognition

I know [Singapore](https://www.moe.gov.sg/docs/default-source/document/education/syllabuses/sciences/files/primary_mathematics_syllabus_pri1_to_pri5.pdf) and [Brazil](http://movimentopelabase.org.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/BNCC_Competencias_Progressao.pdf) explicitly adopt [metacognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacognition) as one of their maths curricular pillars.

The relevance of metacognition is recognized by OECD that has written a [state-of-the-art report](http://www.oecd.org/publications/critical-maths-for-innovative-societies-9789264223561-en.htm) about how to use the theory and its impact in math performance.

Given this importance, I would like to know if there are other countries that also adopt metacognition in their official math curricula.

Comment: How is this related to math education?

Comment: Can you give a reference for the Singapore/Brazil info?  That is interesting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't related to math or to math education.

Comment: @BPP I guess you're unaware: Research into the role of students' level of metacognition in their mathematics educations shows the importance of understanding students' cultivating metacognition for their improved learning in mathematics. [See, for yourself](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C50&q=metacognition+in+mathematics+education&oq=metacognition+in+math).

Comment: @BPP, here are some references about the role metacognition in math education:

(1) An OECD report: [Critical Maths for Innovative Societies
The Role of Metacognitive Pedagogies](http://www.oecd.org/publications/critical-maths-for-innovative-societies-9789264223561-en.htm).

(2) A Springer Book: [Cognition, Metacognition, and Culture in STEM Education
Learning, Teaching and Assessment](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783319666570).

Comment: @kcrisman, here they are: (1) [Singapore MOE document](https://www.moe.gov.sg/docs/default-source/document/education/syllabuses/sciences/files/primary_mathematics_syllabus_pri1_to_pri5.pdf) (2) [Dimensões e Desenvolvimento das Competências Gerais da BNCC](http://movimentopelabase.org.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/BNCC_Competencias_Progressao.pdf) (sorry, only in Portuguese).

Comment: @HumbertoJoséBortolossi Metacognition helps in education? Maybe. My question is that it isn't related to math. You can search "metacognition language eduaction" or  even "metacognition in physical education" and still get many articles discussing their relationship.

Comment: @BPP, yes, I agree with you. But, on the other hand, my question may be considered as just a way to measure how strong is this possible relationship between mathematics and metacoginition by counting how many countries had included metacognition in their mah curriculum guidelines explicitly. If more and more countries adopt metacognition in their math curriculum, this is a sign that it worths to study metacognition as math educators. There are other subjects in the same situation: semiotics, philosophy, ... They can be used in many subjects, including Mathematics Education.

Comment: @HumbertoJoséBortolossi Adding the motivation and maybe the links would improve the question. Could edit them in?